# Refreshing NetSuite Sublist/child record in edit mode

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have created an option for selecting and copying the lines to the end of the list in NetSuite item record. Currently i can only see the updates after the reload of the record. Is there any way i can reload or refresh it with in the edit mode. Below i have added the code for creating buttons to select and copy the line item and paste it to the end of the record.

```
function button1Func(type) {
    if (type=='edit' || 'view')
{
    var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
    var intCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
    var headrow = document.getElementById("item_headerrow");
    var head = headrow.insertCell(0);
    head.innerHTML ="Select";
    for (var rep = 1; rep <= intCount; rep++)
        {
            var row = document.getElementById("item_row_"+rep);
            var x = row.insertCell(0);
            var newCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
            newCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            newCheckbox.setAttribute("id", "select_CheckBox"+rep);
            x.appendChild(newCheckbox);
        }
}
}

 function button2Func(type) {
   if (type=='edit' || 'view')
{
    var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
    var intCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
    for (var rep = 1; rep <= intCount; rep++)
        {
            var repId = record.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', rep);
            if(document.getElementById("select_CheckBox"+rep).checked==true){
                makecopyfun(repId);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    alert("Success");
}
 }

     function makecopyfun(repId){
      var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
      var intCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
      record.insertLineItem('item',intCount + 1);
       alert (intCount);
      record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','item',repId);
      record.commitLineItem('item');
      var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858783/netsuite-sublist-child-record-does-not-update-refresh-in-edit-mode

Comment: I saw this answer before i submit this question. I didn't ask for the same. my situation is different. i explained the same is the description.@Wenson